# Get bootstrap accordion height

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use HTML2Canvas with jsPDF to save some accordions to the pdf. Accordions are created dynamically with javascript and i'm trying to get their height to save them to pdf (i need to split the page at some point and save them in separate images because they're way too big). I've gathered all the accordions with their classname:

```
function gatherAccordions(){
    //Launched on button click
    var accordionArr = document.getElementsByClassName("akkordion");
    for (var i = 0; i<accordionArr.length;i++){
        console.log(accordionArr[i]);
        console.log(accordionArr[i].clientHeight); //returns 0
    }
}
```

Edit: as i read a bit more i got that .clientHeight will return 0 in case height is not set in CSS. I decided to try the jQuery approach which was highly suggested. Although it returned me -2 (which obviously can't be the right height).

```
function gatherAccordions(){
    var accordionArr = document.getElementsByClassName("akkordion");
    for (var i = 0; i<accordionArr.length;i++){
        console.log(accordionArr[i]);
        console.log($("#"+accordionArr[i].id).height()); //returns -2
    }
}
```

Any ideas how could I approach this thing? I have to note that the accordions (as you can see from code below) are not the bottom elements of the accordion tree, there are several divs and other stuff below it. If i gave .height() to accordionBody and accordionhead separately i did recieve -20 and -31 as a result height, which also sounds weird (being negative). Also, when i added elements to the accordion body then the height of body did not increase although visually i can clearly tell that it did.

This builds the accordions:

```
/*
    #Builds the head of accordion which contains main stats
*/
function buildAccordionHead(player){
    //player has attributes: coef, ratio, pos, hasplayed, name, points
    //This is the panel that holds the player main information (coef,name,pos etc)
    var accordionHead = document.createElement("div");
    accordionHead.className = "panel-heading";
    accordionHead.dataset.parent = "#accordion";
    accordionHead.dataset.toggle = "collapse";
    accordionHead.setAttribute('href', "#id_"+player.pos);
    //This is the container for positioning items
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.className = "container-fluid";
    //Create playerrow (FN06)
    var upper_row = rowCreate("KOHT","","K","S","P",true);
    var playerRow = rowCreate(player.pos,player.name,player.coef,player.ratio,player.score,false);
    //Add row(s) to the children of container
    container.appendChild(upper_row);
    container.appendChild(playerRow);
    //Add container to the children of accordion head
    accordionHead.appendChild(container);
    return accordionHead;
}
/*
    Builds the body of the accordion which contains history 
*/

function buildAccordionBody(player,round){
    //moving inside out!
    //generates container-fluid element with a rows inside
    if (even){
        var containerfluid = historyRowEven(player);
    }
    else{
        var containerfluid = historyRowOdd(player,round);
    }
    var bodyel = document.createElement("div");
    bodyel.className = "panel-body";
    bodyel.appendChild(containerfluid);
    var collapser = document.createElement("div");
    collapser.id = "id_"+player.pos;
    collapser.className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    collapser.appendChild(bodyel);
    return collapser;
}

/*
    The main builder function!
*/
function buildAccordion(player,round){
    //This is outer panel
    var accordionPanel = document.createElement("div");
    accordionPanel.className = "panel panel-default akkordion";
    var accordionHeading = buildAccordionHead(player);
    var accordionBody = buildAccordionBody(player,round);
    //Add accordion head to the children of accordion-panel
    accordionPanel.appendChild(accordionHeading);
    accordionPanel.appendChild(accordionBody);
    accordionPanel.id = "collapser_id_"+player.pos;
    //Add accordion-panel to the children of div with accordion
    var mainElement = document.getElementById("accordion");
    mainElement.appendChild(accordionPanel);
}
```